# Dynamically add items to Tkinter Canvas

Tags: python, dynamic, tkinter-canvas

I'm attempting to learn Tkinter with the goal of being able to create a 'real-time' scope to plot data. As a test, I'm trying to draw a polygon on the canvas every time the 'draw' button is pressed. The triangle position is randomized. I have two problems:

1. There is a triangle on the canvas as soon as the program starts, why and how do I fix this?
2. It doesn't draw any triangles when I press the button, at least none that I can see.

Code:

```
from Tkinter import *

from random import randint

class App:
    
    def __init__(self,master):
        
        #frame = Frame(master)
        #frame.pack(side = LEFT)
        
        self.plotspc = Canvas(master,height = 100, width = 200, bg = "white")
        self.plotspc.grid(row=0,column = 2, rowspan = 5)
        
        self.button = Button(master, text = "Quit", fg = "red", \
                             command = master.quit)
        self.button.grid(row=0,column=0)
        
        self.drawbutton = Button(master, text = "Draw", command = \
                               self.pt([50,50]))
        self.drawbutton.grid(row = 0, column = 1)        
        
    def pt(self, coords):
        coords[0] = coords[0] + randint(-20,20)
        coords[1] = coords[1] + randint(-20,20)
        x = (0,5,10)
        y = (0,10,0)
        xp = [coords[0] + xv for xv in x]
        yp = [coords[1] + yv for yv in y]
        ptf = zip(xp,yp)
        self.plotspc.create_polygon(*ptf)        

    if __name__ == "__main__":
        root = Tk()
        app = App(root)
        root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 5):

`command=self.pt([50,50])` (that you use in the `Button` call which builds the Draw button) *immediately executes* the call you're telling it to execute, and binds the result (`None`) to `command`.  Use, instead, in that same:

```
, command=lambda: self.pt([50, 50]) )
```

to delay the execution of the call to each time that button will be pressed.